# Chrome Notification in a packaged app. "chrome.notifications.create"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

Here is my code. I'm not sure whether this is supposed to work.

```
$('#save').bind('click', function(e){

var opt = {
    type: "basic",
    title: "Deploy",
    message: "It worked!"
  };
chrome.notifications.create("", opt, function(id) {});
});
```

I have my permissions set up to use notifications, so I think that isn't the problem.

Comment: There is a syntax error in there: `function(id) {);}` should be just `function(id) {}`

Comment: I just updated that bug, but still no luck

Comment: Please update the question to confirm that you're using Linux (which doesn't have support yet for Rich Notifications). Also see https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/rich-notifications if you don't understand the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications#type-NotificationOptions) lists `iconUrl` as a **required option** for `opt` in `chrome.notifications.create`.

So suppose you add a picture `icon.png` to the root of your extension. Then your code can be modified like that:

```js
var opt = {
   type: "basic",
   title: "Deploy",
   message: "It worked!",
   iconUrl: "icon.png"
};
chrome.notifications.create("", opt, function(id) {
   if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
     console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
   }
});
```

This should work, and in case there is any problem with the notification you'll get informed in the console.

Comment: I'm getting this error.

TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined

Comment: @Blynn Well, I meant `chrome.notifications.create` (I just quoted the docs). I'll update the answer.

Comment: I reading through the documentation, but its a bit confusing.  How do I apply this to my code.. I guess I need to define an ID and callback?

Comment: I think this isn't available in the stable channel yet that's my problem.  Thanks for all your help.